# Multisite WP. CSS won't load

Tags: css, wordpress

The CSS for this website will not load. http://directory.zelenopol.net/

However, other sites are fine – (http://zelenopol.net/, http://ask.zelenopol.net). They have the same theme.

I've tried clearing the cache, but there's no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look in all the links you mention, I think the problem is in one css file. Both zelenopol.net and ask.zelenopol.net load the file correctly. In both cases it loads from the
http://uploads.zelenopol.net/wp-content/uploads/dynamic_avia/enfold.css?ver=1.

In the case of directory.zelenopol.net, this file is not loaded. If you look at the markup you will see that it tries to load the http://directory.zelenopol.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/28/dynamic_avia/enfold.css?ver=1 which gives a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about WP Original Media Path plugin.